# Get cart subtotal

Tags: cart, javascript

I'm trying to get the subtotal of the cart and subtract it from a value in javascript.
This is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function minus_number() {
        var a  = document.querySelector("#spend");
        var first_number = '50';
        var second_number = '<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()); ?>';
        var result = parseInt(first_number) - parseInt(second_number);
        a.innerHTML = result;
    }
window.addEventListener("load",minus_number());

</script>
```

However it only shows NAN on the page. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: can you do VIEW-SOURCE (ctrl+U) of the code you shown above and paste here ?

Answer (score 0):

You get NaN here, as second_number variable is not a number (probably, null).
That may happen due to you using the wrong part of totals - basically, you may not have grand total here. Try using next line:
`age::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal()`
The subtotal may be present, while grand total is not yet calculated.